# Create ActiveXObject on *server*

Tags: javascript, asp.net, activexobject

I have created a little html stub that allows a user to compare various spellers.  I would like to include the Word speller and I have written code in a .js file to create an ActiveXObject thus:

```
var wordApp = new ActiveXobject("Word.Application");
```

This works fine on my local machine but I get the dreaded 'Automation server can't create object' error when I try it on other machines.  I have searched and read the various articles on the topic and I understand that what I am trying to do is very,very bad, not safe, doesn't work on any browser than IE, and so on.  This is for an internal test app in a trusted environment and all I want is for others to be able to access the page and see the result without forcing them to make extreme changes to their security settings.

So, here is my question.  Is there a way that I can get this to run *server side* on my machine running IIS and hosting the website?  Ideally I would like to be able to insert my HTML into an aspx file and, when the submit button is pushed, have it either run all the javascript on server side or at least run the portion that calls the activeX code.  If this isn't feasible, can I migrate the specific functions that call the activeX and get the data to C# or VB and still run the safer functions in JS?

Thanks for your advice!

Comment: And one last comment -- I tried to use the [servername] optional parameter to get the instance of word to run on my server but that parameter seems poorly documented and when I use it, the call won't even run on my local machine -- I couldn't find any advice on how to use it properly -- just another possible solution if anyone knows much about it.  Thanks!

Comment: Does your server really have Word installed?

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757